# Where we can find database designs schemes (ERD or other) for very common use cases?

Tags: database, database-design, resources, erd

The question is more simple than what it looks. There are many use cases that are well known and people have put a lot of thought into them. For example: Audit trailing, login users, and so on.  We are looking for a good resource site that present the DB design for those common use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out

http://databaseanswers.org/

There are over 500 data models available for free there.  It's not hard to convert them into a working database.  For some of them, if you contact the webmaster, they will send you a working MS Access application with a built in database.

Even if you don't use Access this could serve as a prototype.

Comment: Hello Walter: Thanks for your reply.  I think you are making reference to this page: http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm, Thanks for the lead again.

Answer (score 0):

Try [The Data Model Resource Book by Len Silverston](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237). It has 3 volumes and not only shows but also explains the usual use cases.